# Prove $R$ is commutative if $x^2=x$ for every $x\in R$.

Tags: ring-theory

I need to prove that $R$ is commutative, that is for each $x,y\in R$ $xy=yx$.
I think for a ring to be commutative, it needs identity such that $1_R\cdot x=x=x\cdot 1_R$, $1_R\not=0_R$.

so,   $xy=1_R(xy)=1_Rx\cdot 1_Ry=1_Ry\cdot 1_Rx=(yx)1_R=yx$ Dose it make sense? ----Ok does not make sense!

Comment: What is $R$? Also, unless your definition of a ring requires the existence of $1_R$, there's no need to have an identity in a commutative ring. Your proof also seems to assume that $1_R x$ and $1_R y$ commute, which is really what you're trying to prove.

Comment: What is $R$? If you purpose $R$ is ring, $R$ does not satisfy $xy=yx$ for each $x,y\in R$ in general.

Comment: $R$ is a ring. And I am totally lost in the class.

Comment: So, what should I try?

Comment: @Wes Not all rings are commutative, and not all rings containing $1$ are commutative. Without a *lot* more information, the problem isn't true.

Comment: Ok, I think that's why i need to prove this case(?) is commutative somehow.

Comment: @Wes If $R$ is an arbitrary ring, then it's not guaranteed to be commutative. Please read the problem again.

Comment: @T.Bongers So, you mean I cannot be sure there is multiplicative inverse or identity either? Please give some guide line to start.

Comment: @Wes In an arbitrary ring, there need not be any multiplicative inverses or identity. As I've said, the claim is false. Please read the original question again.

Comment: Let $R$ be a ring such that for every $x\in R$, we have $x^2=x$. Prove that $R$ is commutative. In other words, for each $x,y\in R$, prove that $xy=yx$

Comment: That condition $x^2=x$ is **huge**.

Comment: @Wes That condition is extremely important and is completely missing from your original post.

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh...sorry..  I didn't realize that was important... What makes different?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks. I looked through it but I don't understand the last part. Why $xy+yx=0$ becomes $yx=-yx=xy$ by characteristic 2? What is characteristic 2?

Answer (score 19):

Take $(x+x)^2=(2x)^2=4x^2=4x$. From the other hand, you have $(x+x)^2=x+x=2x$. So $4x=2x$, i.e. $2x=0$ for any $x$. In other words, $x=-x$ for any $x$.

Take $x+y=(x+y)^2$. Then you have $x+y=x^2+y^2+xy+yx=x+y+xy+yx$. From this you can conclude that $xy+yx=0$, i.e. $xy=-yx=yx$. The last equality follows from the first paragraph.

Comment: You do have to be a little bit careful on the first paragraph if the ring has characteristic 2. Then x+x = 0 so you get it anyway.